# How to make Allegro Common Lisp case sensitive?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

How do I make Allegro Lisp case sensitive.  I've tried the following

```
(setf (readtable-case rt) :default)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears the docs are wrong but this appears to work I think.

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
```

Comment: What docs are wrong?  You didn't  link to any docs.  :default isn't a standard value for readtable case, but :invert is.  They're all listed in [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_rdtabl.htm).

Comment: Maybe you were talking about [Allegro's documentation](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/case.htm), but note that that says about using :default, "If you have used setf to modify a readtable's readtable-case to one of the ANSI-specified settings, then that readtable's readtable-case is not changed by subsequent calls to set-case-mode unless/until that readtable-case is set to :default."  So :default only has special meaning in conjunction with Allegro's set-case-mode.  You haven't told us whether you did anything with set-case-mode or not.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes it appears they are not technically wrong but they didn't really post a working example.  I don't understand the quoted sentence at all.

Comment: There's interaction between another allegro function (set-case-mode)and read table case. If you set read table case explicitly, then set-case-mode doesn't have effect unless you set read table case to (the non-standard) value :default.